# How do React hooks such as 'isLoading' update?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-query

I just want to check my understanding of how certain React hooks are working. If I have the following react app, for example:

```js
// _app.js

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps: { ...pageProps }}) {

  return (
      <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
      </QueryClientProvider>
  )
}
```

And then the following component:

```js
// MyComponent.js

export default function MyComponent() {
    const {data, isLoading} from useQuery()

    if (isLoading) return <div>loading..</div>

    return <div>{data}<div/>
}
```

It probably sounds like a stupid question, but I just want to verify that the way I am thinking about hooks is valid. Am I right in thinking that the following sequence is the kind of thing that generally occurs?

1. The page is loaded
2. `QueryClientProvider` is assessed by React
3. MyComponent is assessed by React, and the useQuery hook is called, returning `{data: [], isLoading: true}`
4. The page is rendered with the message "loading..."
5. `queryClient` finishes fetching data from the API
6. THE MUTATION OF `queryClient`'s PROPERTIES AFTER THE DATA LOADS **CAUSES** REACT TO RE-ASSESS `QueryClientProvider` AND ITS CHILDREN
7. because of this, `useQuery` is called again, yielding {data: ["data1, "data2"], isLoading: false}
8. The page is re-rendered with the data in place
9. This is the general mechanism by which things like `isLoading` are updated

Comment: `6. THE MUTATION OF queryClient's PROPERTIES AFTER THE DATA LOADS CAUSES REACT TO RE-ASSESS QueryClientProvider AND ITS CHILDREN` I'm not familiar with the innerworkings of useQuery, but this  is definitely false. The only way to cause react to rerender is to set state. React pays no attention to mutations.

Comment: @NicholasTower There are a few things that will cause React to re-render. One of them is updating component props.

Comment: `One of them is updating component props.` You're right that changing props may be the reason that an individual component is rerendering, but the only reason the props are changing in the first place is that some component farther up the tree set state.

Comment: Not sure about that. If I *am* wrong I'd like to know what the actual mechanism is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 6. THE MUTATION OF queryClient's PROPERTIES AFTER THE DATA LOADS CAUSES REACT TO RE-ASSESS QueryClientProvider AND ITS CHILDREN

This step is incorrect. React has no way to tell when an object is mutated. The only way that react knows that it needs to rerender is because some code somewhere calls set state. Setting the state may trigger a cascade of other components rendering due to changes in props or context, but it's always kicked off by setting state<sup>1</sup>.

Setting state is ultimately what react-query is doing as well, though it is buried quite deeply. The spot in react-query's code that sets the state is [this line](https://github.com/TanStack/query/blob/main/packages/react-query/src/useBaseQuery.ts#L81), and it does so with the hook [useSyncExternalStore](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usesyncexternalstore). This is a hook you will almost never use yourself, which is intended for library authors who have an external store of data that can be subscribed to. `useSyncExternalStore`'s job is to make sure that external state stays consistent, even when used with react's recently added Concurrent Rendering feature.

There's no call to setState on these lines, but that's because it's buried inside the implementation of `useSyncExternalStore`. React will subscribe to the external state that react-query has, and when react-query calls back to let react know the value has changed, react sets state. [The code that sets state can be found here](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/main/packages/use-sync-external-store/src/useSyncExternalStoreShimClient.js#L110) (they've named the set state function "forceUpdate", but it was returned by calling `useState` a few lines before, so it's just a normal state)

---

So i would change step 6 to:

6. queryClient calls back to react to tell it that the value has changed, and react sets state in the component that called useQuery. Since state was set, the component rerenders.

Note that it's going to be MyComponent that rerenders, not MyApp and QueryClientProvider. Those don't need to render again unless something extra is happening.

---

<sup>1) Technically, class components do have a second way you can kick off a render: this.forceUpdate. But don't use this.forceUpdate.</sup>

Comment: OK, I concede. This was very helpful, thank you.